# To get image src with phpquery from html page

Tags: phpquery

How do i get img src with phpQuery from html page?
Added: I need to get this 'src' to use in parser module for drupal

Comment: I have already defined it, and have it works on another type of content e.g. p, div, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a short example

```
$imgsrc = pq('div#foo img.pic')->attr('src');
```

Comment: Tried to use in this code
$page->find('div.text.img ->attr('src')')->html();
but got t_string error

Comment: Try this $page->find('div.text.img')->attr('src')->html();